# Using ng-repeat in directive causing form validation not working properly

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

In html,

```
<form name="textform" novalidate>
    <cms-radio name="color" require="true" option="[{title:'Red', value:'red'},{title:'Orange', value:'orange'},{title:'Green', value:'green'}]" ng-model="color"></cms-radio>
</form>
```

In JS,

```
angular.module('cmsRadio',[]).directive('cmsRadio', function(){
'use strict';

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            name:'@',
            require:'=',
            option:"=",
            bindedModel: "=ngModel"
        },
        replace:true,    
        templateUrl: 'radio.html'
    };
});
```

In radio.html

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form="{{name}}" ng-class="{'has-error':{{name}}.$invalid && {{name}}.$dirty}" >
    <div class="radio" ng-repeat='item in option'>
           <label><input type="radio" name="{{name}}" ng-model="bindedModel" value="{{item.value}}" ng-required="require">{{item.title}}</label>
    </div>
    <span class="has-error" ng-show='{{name}}.$dirty && {{name}}.$invalid' ng-message='{{name}}.$error'>
            <p class="control-label" ng-messsage='require'>{{name}} is required.</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

When I click on the first radio button, it shows the error as follow.

[image]

The error disappeared only if I clicked on the three radio buttons. How to prevent the error appeared when only one of the radio button is clicked instead of three? Anyone could help?

**EDIT: MY SOLUTION**

In html,

```
<cms-radio label="Color" name="color" require="true" option="[{'answers':[{'title':'Red', 'value':'red'},{'title':'Orange', 'value':'orange'},{'title':'Green', 'value':'green'}],'selectedAnswer':null}]" id="color" class=""></cms-radio>
```

In JS,

```
 angular.module('cmsRadio',[]).directive('cmsRadio', function(){
    'use strict';

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                name:'@',
                require:'=',
                option:"="
            },
            replace:true,    
            templateUrl: 'radio.html'
        };
    });
```

In radio.html

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form="{{name}}" ng-class="{'has-error':{{name}}.$invalid && {{name}}.$dirty}" >
        <div ng-repeat="item in option">
            <div class="radio" ng-repeat="answer in item.answers">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="{{name}}" ng-model="item.selectedAnswer" value="{{answer.value}}" ng-required="require">{{answer.title}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="has-error" ng-show='{{name}}.$dirty && {{name}}.$invalid' ng-message='{{name}}.$error'>
                <p class="control-label" ng-messsage='require'>{{name}} is required.</p>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form validation break in directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227912/form-validation-break-in-directive)

Comment: Hi @miensol, do u have any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Nope, please try to create a jsfiddle or plunker or codepen demonstrating the issue. Building separate example usually helps to identify what's the problem. I can only suspect an issue in interpolated attributes inside the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not be interpolating the field names in the ng-show and ng-class directives.

Rather than duplicating `scope.name` for both the form AND the input names, try giving the form a fixed name (e.g. 'radioList') e.g.:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-form="radioList" ng-class="{'has-error':radioList[name].$invalid && radioList[name].$dirty}" >
    <div class="radio" ng-repeat='item in option'>
           <label><input type="radio" name="{{name}}" ng-model="bindedModel" value="{{item.value}}" ng-required="require">{{item.title}}</label>
    </div>
    <span class="has-error" ng-show='radioList[name].$dirty && radioList[name].$invalid' ng-message='radioList[name].$error'>
            <p class="control-label" ng-messsage='require'>{{name}} is required.</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The answer above was misguided. The issue had nothing to do with the interpolation of name. It was simply that the ng-repeat was creating a child scope and the ng-model did not have a '.' in it, and therefore each child scope was getting its own copy of `bindedmodel`.

If the directive used the `controllerAs` option this would not be a problem. However, the simplest solution here where we are using scope directly is to compensate for the child scope by using `$parent` as below:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':{{name}}.$invalid && {{name}}.$dirty}" >
    <div class="radio" ng-repeat='item in option'>
           <label><input type="radio" name="{{name}}" ng-model="$parent.bindedModel" value="{{item.value}}" ng-required="require && !bindedModel">{{item.title}}</label>
    </div>
    <span class="has-error" ng-show="{{name}}.$invalid  && {{name}}.$dirty" ng-messages='{{name}}.$error'>
      <p class="control-label" ng-messsage='require'>{{name}} is required.</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/uo4OcG9R5vzNVVvKxTXv?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, @Phil Degenhardt, the main cause is from the ng-repeat. It breaks the validation. However, problem solved when I using 2nd level of ng-repeat. Anyway, thank for your answering.

Comment: That is completely wrong: ng-repeat does NOT break validation. As for the second level of ng-repeat - there was no second level of ng-repeat in the original question - you've changed the fundamental nature of the directive from a radio button list to a list of radio button lists and accidentally bypassed your real problem.

Comment: I tried your answer, but it doesn't work. Do have live example?

Comment: No I have adapted code I run locally. If you have a plunkr, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Phil Degenhardt, here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/z939ft3o4Kic02aPeHr6?p=preview

Comment: @user2991183,  the creation of child scope by the ng-repeat in conjunction with a dotless ngModel binding that was the issue. I missed it because in the code I adapted I was using controllerAs. See correct answer above.

Comment: your updated plunkr seem like not working for validation also... I tried do some testing, changing the `ng-show="{{name}}.$invalid  && {{name}}.$dirty"` of the error message to `ng-show="{{name}}.$invalid"` to make the error message to be display at the start. Since the form is invalid without clicking any radio button, the error message should come out. But, yours didn't have any error shown.

Comment: I found the bug. The updated code is missing `ng-form="{{name}}"` Thanks for your great solution!

Comment: I have one more question, do you know how to set the default value for the radio button? let say, I want to set the default value like this: `<cms-radio selectedAnswer="red"> </cms-radio>`  and pass to the default value to directive, any ideas?

Comment: You should do this in your model.